# Need explanation why adding content to a div makes it change position

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs placed side by side. When I'm trying to put a header (or any element) inside of the middle div (or any div), that div floats way down. Why does it do that?
CSS I used for divs:

```
    div {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: lightgray;
      height: 600px;
      width: 300px;
   }
```

Comment: Clarify your question by adding HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Add `*{box-sizing:border-box}` to your CSS. It defines how the width and height of an element are calculated.